# Problems sending a request to an API in Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, api, request, put

I have a problem connecting to an API. My request seems to be ok, but it seems like my authentification isnßt correct. Can anybody help me?

The url, and the API-Put-request is correct, i tested it with the mozilla HTTP-Requester. But i have no success. I get HTTP 403 as response code, so i think there is something wrong with my authentification.

I am very new at Android Studio and the neccesary java-programming. So it would be great if anybody had a hint for me :-)

Here is my code (it is already in an async task and i get no NetworkInMainThreadException)

I also get "method does not support a request body: PUT", but i think this is because of the authentification.

```
        public String doWork(String pMail, String pPassword, String pNickname) {
    String output = "";
    try {


            //authentification header?
            Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                @Override
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(
                            "admin@domain.com", "password".toCharArray());
                }
            });

            //Test: These parameters need to be sent from the GUI
            pMail = "name@domain.com";
            pPassword = "Testpassword";
            pNickname = "Testuser";

            String password = "password";
            String username = "admin@domain.com";
            //new try for authentification
            String authstring = username + ":" + password;

            byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encode(authstring.getBytes(), 0);

            URL url = new URL("https://domain/API");

            //create https connection
            HttpsURLConnection httpsCon = null;
            httpsCon = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpsCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authEncBytes);
            httpsCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
            httpsCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpsCon.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "de");

            OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                    httpsCon.getOutputStream());

            out.write("/Users/" + pMail + "/" + pPassword + "/" + pNickname);
            out.close();

            httpsCon.getInputStream();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            output = e.toString();
        System.out.println(output);

        }
    return output;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. This block of code worked for me. this is doInBackground method in AsyncTask class.

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {

    try {



        URL url = new URL ("https://url.com/systems.json");

        String userPassword = "blah" + ":" + "blah";

        byte[] encodingBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(userPassword.getBytes());
        String encoding = new String(encodingBytes);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding); //basic http authetication
        connection.connect();

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
        in.close();
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

In onPostExecute im taking a string as an argument which is the feed that this block of code got. Hope this helps.

**EDIT: Actually your issue seems that you are tryying to run doWork method in UI thread. Move the code from doWork method to AsyncTask doInBackground method and exception won't be thrown anymore.**

Answer (score 0):

By the way use some library to do the API request, instead of writing it all by yourself. I use Retrofit, but there is probably some other good libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i used Volley to get my task, and now my Put and Post and Delete work. I have just one Question left: How can i get the output as a JSon-Object?

My first Idea is to change this method from void to any data-type (like String, Map or anything else) and add "return" at the end.
My second idea is directly handling the JSon in the method.

Can anybody please give me a hint?

public void getUserGroups(String pUserID)
    {
        String getCommand = "";
        getCommand = API_URL + "Groups/Group/" + pUserID;

```
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, getCommand, new Response.Listener<String>()
    {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // Do i get my output here? ################################
            // #########################################################

            //here we have to check the response code
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                //success
            }
            else
            {
                //error-code
            }
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //You can handle error here if you want
                }
            }){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<>();

            String credentials = KEY_EMAIL + ":" + KEY_PASSWORD;
            String encodedCredentials = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP);
            headers.put("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials);
            //returning parameter
            return headers;
        }
    };


    //Adding the string request to the queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```